# Plotar um groupby com duas colunas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Boa noite, estou tentando plotar em um gráfico um groupby que fiz de uma tabela.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files
```

link do arquivo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zzqEUdUL3pqMbcCLi44JHNj5utU7RjPL/view

```
files.upload()
clientes = pd.read_csv('Ecommerce_Customers.csv')

time_money = clientes.round({'Time on Website': 0, 'Yearly Amount Spent': 0}).groupby(["Time on Website", "Yearly Amount Spent"])[[]].sum()
time_money
```

o que me gera a seguinte saída.

[image: output do groupby]

Meu problema é, não estou achando um jeito de plotar essa gráfico, já pesquisei bastante, achei diversas formas de plotar, mas nenhuma que se encaixe no meu problema.

Desde já agradeço quem tentou ajudar

Comment: Importante você informar qual seria o seu problema, pois me parece bem provável que as soluções apresentadas sejam bem similares às formas de plotar que você precisa. Diga qual o tipo de gráfico que precisa e quais métricas você gostaria em cada eixo (se houver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa, tudo bom?

O problema aqui é que você está resumindo o seu dataframe a apenas 2 índices, sem colunas, o que atrapalha bastante na hora de distribuir os valores.

Tem várias formas de trabalhar o dataframe de modo a viabilizar a plotagem do seu gráfico, mas eu optei por uma solução que apenas adapta o código que você já tinha feito.

```
time_money = clientes.round({'Time on Website': 0, 'Yearly Amount Spent': 0}).groupby("Time on Website").sum()
time_money
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora que você já tem seu dataframe agrupado pelo tempo gasto no website, como index, basta plotar a coluna que você deseja:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.plot(time_money.index, time_money['Yearly Amount Spent'])
plt.xlabel('Time on Website')
plt.ylabel('Yearly ammount Spent');
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que tenha ajudado, boa sorte com o seu problema!